# Using Skia in Android NDK

Tags: android, skia

Is it true that android.graphics.* depends on the native Skia library?
If so, is it possible to access the Skia library in my native C/C++ codes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Skia is not offered as a lib/sharedlib inside android, as its 
api is not guaranteed to be stable over time.

there is no sample implementation of controls in C/C++, all the widget/view 
sub-system is done in Java

for skia 
http://code.google.com/p/skia/

Comment: Thanks, Rishabh. A followup question, is it possible to custom build the skia lib and include it in my jni? If so, how to do that?

Comment: Check this out this will help 


http://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/android_sample/SampleApp?r=1452

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 5):

Skia can be use using native c/c++ code but you need android source to build your app and generate lib<>.so and apk because its make needs external/skia/..... in Android.mk[sample code as indicated by Rishabh]

Actually I tried one sample in which i pass canvas object to my native code using JNI and drawXXX() on canvas using skia apis.

You can refer to 
[Android graphics pipeline](http://www.xenomachina.com/2011/05/androids-2d-canvas-rendering-pipeline.html)
to understand android graphics pipleline.

Answer (score 4):

> This is a minimal Android app that uses JNI and Skia to do rendering.

https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+/master/platform_tools/android/examples/hello_skia_app/

Comment: 404, not found.

Comment: https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-external-skia/tree/master/platform_tools/android/examples/hello_skia_app

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_external_skia/tree/master/platform_tools/android/examples/hello_skia_app

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing using AOSP it's very simple - you can link previously built libskia.so in your NDK app