# Using SKIA library instead of Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, skia

While I am researching about 2D rendering pipeline of android,
I came to know a graphic library SKIA written in C++.

But I am not sure it can be used instead of android Canvas.

Can it be used as a replacement of the Canvas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: afaik android uses skia internally

Comment: If it's true, can I modify SKIA code to customize drawing algorithm?

Comment: sure, see http://source.android.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can find information here:
[Using Skia in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342258/using-skia-in-android-ndk)

All UI animation performed by Android are implementing using SKIA, but is very inefficient for huge graphical stuff since it does not use the graphic hardware available on the phone.

Comment: The actual link to skia+android example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/skia/+/chrome/m39/platform_tools/android/examples/hello_skia_app

Answer (score 1):

The Skia library *is* the `Canvas`, by and large. See: [How do the pieces of Android's (2D) Canvas drawing pipeline fit together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762727/how-do-the-pieces-of-androids-2d-canvas-drawing-pipeline-fit-together)