# Does Android internally use Skia for drawing text on bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, skia

I am dealing with an application which has to rapidly draw text on bitmaps. I've pretty much optimized the memory usage of the rendering process but I still want the process to be as fast as possible and that's when I learned about the Skia library which some people say it can provide superior performance compared to native Android canvas. After some googling, I heard that Android already uses Skia for UI rendering and I am wondering if I will gain any performance if I start using Skia to render text on bitmaps instead of using Android canvas ?

Comment: i have removed the `If not, is there any alternative that you would recommend?` part of your question, as asking for libraries is off-topic for stack overflow, although the rest of your question (asking if android uses Skia library internally) seems fine :)

Comment: That's okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Android versions before 3.0 used SKIA for drawing, from 3.0 HWUI is used. You can see this article about [The Android graphics subsystem](https://www.imgtec.com/blog/learning-about-the-android-graphics-subsystem/) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342258/using-skia-in-android-ndk).